# Mouse leave event keeps firing in navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, mouseevent

Here is a link to the item in question:
http://www.nychukdesign.com/uploads/dynamic-top-bar-nav-menu.html

All HTML, Javascript and CSS is in the one html file

**Functionality description:**
This is a simple dynamic horizontal navigation bar that is intended to disappear when a user scrolls down the page, in which a trigger is activated when the user mouses into the area, of which it slides down and reappears, and disappears once more upon mousing out. When the user scrolls back to the top the navigation returns to it's default (static) state...which is where the problem comes in.

**Problem description:**
Sometimes (and yes I can not re-create this problem every time) when you return to the top of the page, and the navigation returns to it's default state, when the mouse leaves this area (without scrolling down again) the navigation will slide up and disappear. Sometime it will happen on the first try, sometimes after several, and primarily in Firefox 2.0, although I have had it happen once or twice in Safari.

**My thoughts:**
I am baffled by this, and why I am seeking help. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**To re-create the problem**
*Update:* I just discovered how to re-create the problem. You must scroll down and trigger the menu at least once, before scrolling back to the top, in which mousing over the menu will for some reason make it disappear.

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Use short notation of DOM ready

$(function(){

// Assign variables for the menu, the trigger and the menu position (relative to the document)
var menu = $('#menu'),
    menuTrigger = $('#menu-trigger'),
    pos = menu.offset();

    // Listen for the scroll event
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        // If we scroll past the position of the menu's height and it has it's default style, then hide menu. 
        if($(this).scrollTop() > pos.top+menu.height() && menu.hasClass('default')){
            menu.fadeOut('fast', function(){
                  // Remove the default class and replace with fixed class
                  $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('fixed'); 
            });
            // Initiate the trigger to show and hide the menu with the mouse event
                   $(menuTrigger).removeClass('hidden').addClass('block').mouseenter(function(){
                $(menu).slideDown('fast').mouseleave(function(){
                $(menu).slideUp('fast');
                });
                });
        // If we scroll back to top and menu has fixed class, fadeIn menu
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
            menu.fadeIn('fast', function(){
                // Hide the trigger
                $(menuTrigger).removeClass('block').addClass('hidden');

                // Give menu default style
                $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('default');
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post code here, and not a link to some code.  When that link inevitably breaks in the near future, this question will not be of any use to the community.

Comment: Ok sorry Ray, it just seemed like a lot but I will put it below: